# How to build a custom file system for Linux?

Tags: ruby, linux, filesystems

Where should I start if I want to build a filesystem for Linux? Would it be possible to write it in Ruby (at least some part of it)? The file system would be mounted in my home directory so I guess I would need to use FUSE somehow right?

Answer (score 2):

It looks like there is a tutorial at https://debian-administration.org/article/619/Creating_Filesystems_with_Ruby__and_FUSE on writing FUSE filesystems in Ruby.